# Can jQuery listen to browser events?

Tags: jquery, browser-history

Can jQuery listen to browser events?

I want to attach a listener to the browser's `back` and `forward` buttons using jQuery.

Is there anything what I can do, like with `keypress`, `mousewheel`, `click`, to detect when the `back` or `forward` button is clicked? (BTW: not `hashchange`)

Comment: what 'prev page' or 'next page' click?  Do you mean history navigation?

Comment: sorry, I am back, yes, I mean browser history navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a small library for catching history events:

http://code.google.com/p/dshistory/

Comment: that is a intersting plungin. have a look for more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`.unload()`](http://api.jquery.com/unload/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).bind('popstate', function(event) {
```

Comment: Popstate is nice, but it's HTML5 only.

Comment: And I think it fires on hashchange too.

Answer (score -1):

Also look at the [JQuery.live(](http://api.jquery.com/live/)) function that can even bind an event watcher to an object that does not yet exist.